# Nginx Map doesn't interpolate variables

Tags: nginx

I am trying to join a variable and a string within the `map` directive in Nginx, but no luck so far. The idea is that any requests to `/press/some-variable-text` should get redirected to `/magazine/some-variable-text`

```
map $uri $new_uri {
    ~^/press/(?<press_id>.+)$ /magazine/$press_id;
}
```

The output of this is be the following string "**/magazine/$press_id**" (it doesn't interpolate the variable). When I remove the prefix `/magazine/` then the variable content is rendered normally.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using nginx 1.10 or earlier. The variable interpolation you're trying doesn't work for me on 1.10, and in the [change log](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES) I found the following entry related to the map directive:

> Changes with nginx 1.11.0
>
> - Feature: the "map" directive supports combinations of multiple
>        variables as resulting values.

Comment: Hey RazerM have you actually tried this variable interpolation within a newer Nginx version  >= 1.11?

Comment: Yes, it works on 1.15